# Probability distributions in quantitative finance

Tags: distribution

What are the most popular probability distributions in quantitative finance and what are their applications?

Comment: Why close? If anything it could be community wiki.

Comment: I would rephrase the question in something like:

What probability distributions are commonly used, what are their properties and what are their applications.

The problems with that are: it depends on your field, the particular model etc. and it's probably better explained on Wikipedia.

Comment: Certainly off-topic as it's currently phrased.  Asking about the "most popular" is inappropriate on any StackExchange site...

Comment: @Shane, I agree it is border line off topic as phrased. But many questions of the "most popular" kind turned out to be really good wikis on SO/SE sites, no?

Comment: It would be much better to rephrase this as a series of specific questions on the major distributions (normal, Poisson, Weibull, Levy-stable, Pareto, etc.).

Comment: BTW, the answer to your question is in chapter 6 of Wilmott's [FAQ in Quantitative Finance](http://www.amazon.com/Frequently-Asked-Questions-Quantitative-Finance/dp/0470748753/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).

Comment: logLaplace is the best fit I can find